# How to do task before copying res to apk and after this

Tags: android, gradle

I have xml file in res/xml and I want to change one node just for building and after that go beck to default value, for example:

before:

```
<resources>
  <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">
    300
  </integer>
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">
    true
  </bool>
  <screenName name="pl.grzeslowski.transport.activities.MainActivity_">
    Main Activity
  </screenName>
  <screenName name="pl.grzeslowski.transport.activities.ResultActivity_">
    Result Activity
  </screenName>
  <string name="ga_trackingId">
      UA-XXXXXXX-Y
  </string>
</resources>
```

After:

```
<resources>
  <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">
    300
  </integer>
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">
    true
  </bool>
  <screenName name="pl.grzeslowski.transport.activities.MainActivity_">
    Main Activity
  </screenName>
  <screenName name="pl.grzeslowski.transport.activities.ResultActivity_">
    Result Activity
  </screenName>
  <string name="ga_trackingId">
    UA-1111111-11111
  </string>
</resources>
```

In my gradle .build I have this task (on the bottom of file) but it doesn't work:

```
task loadAdSense() {

    println "load"
    // saving adsense tag to xml file
    def xmlFile = file("src/main/res/xml/global_tracker.xml")
    def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
    xml.string.each {
        if (it.@name == "ga_trackingId") {
            it.value = adsenseTag
        }
    }
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).print(xml)
}

build.dependsOn loadAdSense

task cleanXml(dependsOn: build) << {

    println "clean"
    // going back with xml
    def xmlFile = file("src/main/res/xml/global_tracker.xml")
    def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
    xml.string.each {
        if (it.@name == "ga_trackingId") {
            it.value = "UA-XXXXXXX-Y"
        }
    }
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).print(xml)
}
cleanXml.dependsOn build
cleanXml.mustRunAfter build
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly? The fils isn't changed or changed in inappropriate moment? In `loadAdSense` task You've no actions declared for tasks. The body task will run at `configuration` phase of gradle's lifecycle.

Comment: it's get loadTask and cleanTask before everything (not depending on tasks)

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand.